# canvas% in frame% doesn't have the frame% size

Tags: canvas, racket

I've create a little snake game in racket and I try to show the borders.

I defined some constantes :

```
(define WIDTH 500)

(define HEIGHT 500)

(define BLK_SIZE 10)
```

so, all block is a 50px square.

I've created a frame%

```
(define frame 
  (new (class frame%
         (define/augment (on-close)
           (send timer stop)
           (printf "ending...\n"))
         (super-new))
       [label "Snake"]
       [width WIDTH]
       [height HEIGHT]))
```

and a canvas%

```
(define game-canvas%
  (class canvas%
    (define/override (on-char e)
      (case (send e get-key-code)
        [(left) (unless (eq? last-dir 'right)
                  (set! dir 'left))]
        [(right) (unless (eq? last-dir 'left)
                   (set! dir 'right))]
        [(up) (unless (eq? last-dir 'down)
                (set! dir 'up))]
        [(down) (unless (eq? last-dir 'up)
                  (set! dir 'down))]
        [else (void)]))
    
    (super-new)))
;...
(define game-canvas (new game-canvas% (parent frame)))
```

I defined the border :

```
(define (create-border)
  (let (
        [nbr-block-x (/ WIDTH BLK_SIZE)]
        [nbr-block-y (/ HEIGHT BLK_SIZE)])
    (append
     (for/list ([x (in-range nbr-block-x)])
       (make-cell x 0))
     (for/list ([x (in-range nbr-block-x)])
       (make-cell x (sub1 nbr-block-x)))
     (for/list ([y (in-range nbr-block-y)])
       (make-cell 0 y))
     (for/list ([y (in-range nbr-block-y)])
       (make-cell (sub1 nbr-block-y) y)))))

(define borders (create-border))
```

And finally I draw the borders :

```
(define-struct cell (x y))

(define (real-world-coordinate elem)
  (make-cell
   (* BLK_SIZE (cell-x elem))
   (* BLK_SIZE (cell-y elem))))

(define (draw-list-of-square! dc square-list)
  (for-each (lambda (elem)
              (send dc draw-rectangle
                    (cell-x (real-world-coordinate elem))
                    (cell-y (real-world-coordinate elem))
                    BLK_SIZE
                    BLK_SIZE))
            square-list))
```

With that code, I except to see borders in my window.
That is the result of the code (without resizing the frame) :

[image: render]

As you can see, the right and down border are outside my frame.

Since I draw block from 0 to `(sub1 nbr-block-x)` (49) (in pixel 490) the borders should appear in my frame.

I've checked the doc of frame% and canvas%. Canvas% define margins which are set to 0 and frame% define `border` and `spacing` which are also set to
0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably too late by now, but it may still be useful to others.

You should let the frame adjust automatically to the canvas rather than the contrary:

```
#lang racket/gui

(define WIDTH 500)
(define HEIGHT 500)

(define frame (new frame% [label "Snake"])) ; no size is specified

(define game-canvas
  (new canvas% [parent frame]
       [min-width WIDTH]
       [min-height HEIGHT]
       [stretchable-width #f] ; To make sure the canvas' sizes stay constant even if the frame is resized with the mouse
       [stretchable-height #f]
       [paint-callback
        (λ(cv dc)
          (send dc set-background "yellow")
          (send dc clear)
          )]))

; Before being shown, the sizes are automatically adjusted.
(send frame show #t)
```

If needed, recalculation of the size can also be forced with

```
(send frame reflow-container)
```

if any size changes after the frame has been shown.